# Jruby on Rails simultaneous save on the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concurrency, jruby, simultaneous

How can I save data on same table if two or more users click save at the same time using Jruby?
Here is a code that I already tried

```
Sequence.transaction do
sq = Sequence.find_by_sequence_key('bus20158001', :lock => true)
sq.values = sq.values + 1
sq.save
end
```

The above code is not working for some reasons
Sequence is my model and its field is (id, sequence_key, values, created_at, updated_at)

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT AT US in your title.

Comment: You want to avoid a race condition when you're incrementing `values` inside Ruby?

Comment: for example my values in sequence is 40 and then two users save at the same time, user1 values became 41 and then user2 values is still 41that it should be 42.

Answer (score 0):

the "simple" answer is you need to make sure the retrieval, increment and save is mutually exclusive :

```
Sequence.exclusively do
  Sequence.transaction do
    sq = Sequence.find_by_sequence_key('bus20158001', :lock => true)
    sq.values = sq.values + 1
    sq.save
  end
end
```

you need a "global" shared mutex e.g. :

```
class Sequence
  @@mutex = Mutex.new
  def exclusively; @@mutex.synchronize { yield } end
end
```

please note that in general this might be a source of contention (esp. if the `find_by` takes some due always looking at the database) ...

... thus the other answer would be to make the values an "atomic" sequence-like counter column at the database level (e.g. you can update it using a trigger on each save based on the current highest value in the table).